# Deploying MEAN app on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have successfully deployed a MEAN app on AWS ECS, but there are a couple things I don't have set-up properly.

1) If I spin up a new task, the Mongo data does not persist between the containers

2) Should my Mongo container and my frontend container be in the same task definition? This seems wrong because I feel like they should be able to scale independently of each other. But if they should be in separate task definitions, do I link them the same way?

Current Architecture:

- 1 Task Defintion

  - contains frontend container and mongo container which are linked
  - I did not define any mounts or volumes (which I assume is why data isn't persisting, but I am struggling to figure out how to properly set this up)
- 1 Cluster
- 1 service

  - contains load balancer and auto-scaling group (when this auto-scaling group creates a new task, I run into the issue of not having data persistence)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you assume is correct. Since you are not defining any mounts the data is not persistent. I recommend using Amazon EFS to Persist Data from Amazon ECS Containers.You can find step by step guide below to achieve the same.

[Using Amazon EFS to Persist Data from Amazon ECS Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-to-persist-data-from-amazon-ecs-containers/)